# How to generate unique id on a distributed system using Oracle Coherence?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, oracle-coherence, sequence-generators

I have a distributed java application which uses Oracle Coherence for caching capabilities. How can I use this to generate a unique UUID for the distributed system? I am pretty sure this can be done by implementing a sequence generator by leveraging on Coherence's cache capabilities as done [here](https://github.com/aseovic/coherence-tools/blob/master/identity/src/main/java/com/seovic/identity/SequenceGenerator.java). Cassandra has [TimeBaseUUID](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/TimeBaseUUIDNotes) and I am trying to find if there is something similar on Coherence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coherence's [UUID class](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22843/com/tangosol/util/UUID.html) has the below constructor which is very much similar to functionality offered by Cassandra's [TimeBasedUUID](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/TimeBaseUUIDNotes).

```
public UUID(long lDatetime,
            java.net.InetAddress addr,
            int nPort,
            int nCount)
```

Coherence Incubator's [UUIDBasedIdentifier](https://github.com/coherence-community/coherence-incubator/blob/develop-12/coherence-common/src/main/java/com/oracle/coherence/common/identifiers/UUIDBasedIdentifier.java) uses the default constructor of `UUID` internally.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything officially supported by Oracle for sequence generation in the Coherence product. It looks like you want UUID generation (not sequence) which is supported by the [Coherence Incubator project in the commons module](http://coherence-community.github.io/coherence-incubator/12.3.1-SNAPSHOT/common/index.html), specifically the [UUIDBasedIdentifier.java](https://github.com/coherence-community/coherence-incubator/blob/develop-12/coherence-common/src/main/java/com/oracle/coherence/common/identifiers/UUIDBasedIdentifier.java) class. There is also the [ClusteredSequenceGeneraror.java](https://github.com/coherence-community/coherence-incubator/blob/develop-12/coherence-common/src/main/java/com/oracle/coherence/common/sequencegenerators/ClusteredSequenceGenerator.java) which can generate cluster wide sequences as well. Please take a look at this project and see if it meets your needs.

The incubator project is written by Oracle developers and is an effort by Oracle to support use cases like yours. Do the due diligence by checking the unit tests to make sure it meets your criteria.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to UUIDBasedIdentifier class which has reference to com.tangosol.util.UUID class. UUID has the right constructor I am looking for.